# Is a spam post recognized as such even if the spam flag is not raised enough times?

Tags: support, spam

To expand on the question in the title, if the following message does NOT appear

[image]

I understand that it means that not enough spam flags were raised. But does it also mean that the post is not recognized as spam by the system? If such a situation arises, can it be rectified, eventually by a mod?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I understand that it means that not enough spam flags were raised.

This is not correct. If this does not appear it means that no spam flags were marked as helpful on the post (either automatically or by a mod).

> If such a situation arises, can it be rectified, eventually by a mod?

A mod would need to undelete the post then flag it as spam (as a mod, that should not require anyone else and should delete the post and approve the flag).

Comment: Interesting... My impression was that notice is displayed if the deletion was the consequence of reaching the flag threshold...

Comment: @JonClements - in a way that's correct too, as reaching the flag threshold will mark all those flags as helpful :)